# GUI multithreading and sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

I'm writing simple GUI to my client server application. GUI client application worked OK but when I added simple Login Form before my client app, communication between client and server doesn't work. Here is the code which create my client GUI (the code is in the "Log in" button in Login Form - when I click the button Login Form is close and client app is open):

```
new testUI().setVisible(true);
dispose(); //close Login Form
```

Comment: SO isn't code generator, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, complable, just about a.m. issue, otherwise this question isn't answerable at all

Comment: "doesn't work" is too vague. What exactly happens? And show your socket-handling code.

Comment: I have GUI app - "testUI" and server - communication is ok. 
I added "LoginForm" which open - "testUI" - (after click the button "Log in" - code above) - testUI doesn't communication with server.

Comment: @mKorbel Said it before, I'll repeat it louder.  *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*

Answer (score 0):

If your login form is not modal, then method setVisible () will return instantly and you will dispose form before user will see it.

Make sure your login form extends JDialog and is created with `modal=true` parameter passed to constructor of JDialog class.

Comment: For more info, check out [How to make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)